# USB Device Model

Tags: usb

I have a question, I want to know which type of controllers are connected to my PC. For example it is a XBox controller or a normal usb gamepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the path you're looking for is:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{745a17a0-74d3-11d0-b6fe-00a0c90f57da}\0017\DriverDesc
```

In the general case, replace the GUID in that path with the GUID in the `ClassGUID` key for your device, and replace the `0017` with the specific device instance from the `Device` key.

Comment: Apologies...  Will have another look.  Have you tried a simple registry search for "Twin USB Gamepad"?  Also, look in your `WINDOWS\inf` directory for the `input.inf` file, do a text search there for "Twin USB Gamepad".